# Joomla link to barebones article content

Tags: html, joomla, hyperlink

I know a trick to make link to article without template (`tmpl=component`), but I see that it still links some styles:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=171:uvjeti-plaćanja&catid=19:poliklinika&Itemid=101&tmpl=component
```

Is it possible to create link to just bare bones data you'd see in content editor for example?

It would be prefferable if nothing else but pure article content is returned. No `html, body, head ...` tags.

Comment: just as you can make a feed, json document, or xml document type you could make a type that is txt or raw and just echo $item->text or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up creating file `raw.php` which contains following code:

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );?><jdoc:include type="component" />
```

I have placed this into my template folder and I can just call it with following url:

```
/?option=com_content&view=article&id=171&catid=19&Itemid=101&tmpl=raw
```

Analog to that you one can make `new.php`, place it to folder of current template in use and call it with `&tmpl=new` argument.